# Rails & Heroku Git Push Issue with Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, c9.io

This is my dir tree
rails-tutorial/
hello_app

I tried to deploy the hello rails app to heroku, but it failed as heroku could not recognize the rails app. So I had to move the contents of the rails app to the root folder(in this case rails-tutorial). It then worked.

Now, I want to create a new app. When I try to create it in the root folder it says "Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first."

What do I do? If I push all the contents into a dir, heroku is not able to recognize it as an app.

Comment: move your files back to ``hello_app``.  Enter into your directory. ( If linux, ``cd hello_app`` ) . Then ``git push heroku ``. Now you can move back to ``rails_tutorial`` and create you new app.

Comment: You can deploy a subfolder using something like this: https://coderwall.com/p/ssxp5q/heroku-deployment-without-the-app-being-at-the-repo-root-in-a-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

When you push to heroku, make sure, you are at the root of project, here is `hello_app`.

In your case `rails-tutorial/hello_app`, you are at folder `rails-tutorial`, you must be move to `hello_app`, just type `cd hello_app` on terminal

You can't create a new rails app inside another. Move out of current rails project, and create other.

In this case. I think, you should move all content of project hello_app to folder `hello_app` under `rails-tutorial`. Them create new rails app sample `new_app` under `rails-tutorial`

```
rails-tutorial    
|__ hello_app
    |__app
    |__bin
    |__config
    |__db
    |__etc...

|__ new_app
    |__app
    |__bin
    |__config
    |__db
    |__etc...
```

Comment: Thanks. This clarified a lot. I didn't know each dir had it's own git.